# Copying fields between array elements in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I'm relatively new to JQ and this might be a simple question.

I have a big, pretty nested JSON file with thousands of *assets*. Each asset always contains one array with two objects (one mother and one child).

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "assets": {
        "array": [
          {
            "id": "7978918",
            "labels": {
              "text": "mother",
              "value": true
            },
            "properties": {
              "context_ids": [],
              "parent": null
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "caa17b2a-4582-4d13-b891-2607e4ba33c6",
            "labels": {
              "text": "child",
              "value": true
            },
            "properties": {
              "context_ids": [],
              "parent": null
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is copying the id from the mother object into the parent field of the child object.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "assets": {
        "array": [
          {
            "id": "7978918",
            "labels": {
              "text": "mother",
              "value": true
            },
            "properties": {
              "context_ids": [],
              "parent": null
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "caa17b2a-4582-4d13-b891-2607e4ba33c6",
            "labels": {
              "text": "child",
              "value": true
            },
            "properties": {
              "context_ids": [],
              "parent": "7978918"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So far I got

```bash
cat test.json | jq '.data[].assets.array[]|=(.properties.parent=.id|select(.labels.text=="mother"))' |less
```

but this, of course, only copies the mother `id` into the mother object's `parent` field and deletes the child object entirely.

I also tried

```bash
cat test.json | jq '.data[].assets.array[].properties += {"parent": .data[].assets.array[0].id} |less
```

On first sight this looked to be correct but seemingly has created a strange loop which never stops and creates a bigger and bigger JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first element is always the mother, this should work just fine:

```
.data[].assets.array |= (.[1].properties.parent = .[0].id)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IzBYbkWSDjb)</sup>

Otherwise sort them by `labels.text` first so that they are always at certain indices.

```
.data[].assets.array |= (sort_by(.labels.text) | .[0].properties.parent = .[1].id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jq '.data |= map(.assets.array | .[1].properties.parent = .[0].id)' test.json
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. A shame that it was that easy 